# A simple query regarding Qt and pointers

Tags: qt, pointers

This isn't like a major doubt but it has been bugging me since I saw it. 
Does this:

```
QObject* f_pObject = this;
```

do the same thing as this:

```
f_pObject = f_pObject->parent();
```

?

PS: I used to be horrible at pointers, and I am renewing my efforts in learning it.

PPS: I don't get the hate. I thought this was an encouraging forum for expert programmers and ones who are learning alike. It's not like I asked for my homework to be done.

Comment: What you mean by "do the same thing as..."? And it is not clear what you are asking. Declaring a variable with initialization (you first code line) is not a same thing as assining an expression to a variable (it doesn't matter what expression). Second line depents on existing value of `f_pObject`.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Thank you for the reply. Please correct me if what I've understood is wrong: The first line initializes a pointer "f_pObject" and assigns it the address to the parent class it is defined in ("this"). In the second line, the parent() function in the class pointed to by f_pObject is called, it returns the address of the parent class, which is again put into f_pObject. So aren't they doing the same thing?

Comment: `this` is not a parent class. It is current class. Your second statement is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at a complete example, interleaved with the output it produces:

```
#include <QtCore>

class P : public QObject { Q_OBJECT };

class C : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QObject * pointer;
public:
   C(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject{parent} {
      pointer = this;
      qDebug() << "this" << this << "pointer" << pointer;
   }
   void test() {
      pointer = pointer->parent();
      qDebug() << "this->parent()" << this->parent() << "pointer" << pointer;
   }
};

int main() {
   P parent;
   C child{&parent};  // this C(0x7fff5e663ac8) pointer C(0x7fff5e663ac8)
   child.test();      // this->parent() P(0x7fff5e663ae0) pointer P(0x7fff5e663ae0)
   C orphan;          // this C(0x7fff5e663aa0) pointer C(0x7fff5e663aa0)
   orphan.test();     // this->parent() QObject(0x0) pointer QObject(0x0)
}
#include "main.moc"
```

The `pointer` (or `f_pObject` in your case) is a variable that points to an object. Its value is completely decoupled from the existence of any particular object. The `pointer` is **not** an object!

It's like having an address of a piece of paper. **Think of the pointer as a piece of paper with an address on it**. Initially you write the address of Ms. C. Hild on it. Then you go to visit Ms. C. Hild to ask her for the address of her parents. She gives the address to you, and you erase and overwrite the piece of paper with an address to Mr. and Ms. P. Arent.

It's obvious that whatever you do to the piece of paper (the pointer) itself has nothing to do with whether the houses of Ms. C. Hild and Mr. and Ms. P. Arent exist.

Ms. C. Hild might be born an orphan, or become an orphan if her parents die (the parent object gets destructed), or if they disown her (the parent object lives on, but the child gets a `setParent(nullptr)`). If any of the objects ("houses") ceases to exist, you end up with a dangling pointer. You have a piece of paper with an address to nowhere.

Comment: Ok! So if I understood you right, in the first line, the address of the current child class in stored in the pointer. And in the second line, the address of the parent class replaces the address of the current child class in the same pointer variable. So if there wasn't a parent class, the pointer would have a null value. Is that right?